# How to write new column conditional on grouped rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame where each **Item** has three categories (a, b,c) and a numeric **Answer** for each category is recorded (either 0 or 1). I would like to create a new column contingent on the rows in the **Answer** column. This is how my data frame looks like:

```
Item     <- rep(c(1:3), each=3)
Option   <- rep(c('a','b','c'), times=3)
Answer   <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)
df       <- data.frame(Item, Option, Answer)


  Item Option Answer
1    1      a      1
2    1      b      1
3    1      c      0
4    2      a      0
5    2      b      0
6    2      c      1
7    3      a      1
8    3      b      1
9    3      c      1
```

What is needed: whenever the three categories in the **Option** column are 1, the **New** column should receive a 1. In any other case, the column should have a 0. The desired output should look like this:

```
  Item Option Answer New
1    1      a      1   0
2    1      b      1   0
3    1      c      0   0
4    2      a      0   0
5    2      b      0   0
6    2      c      1   0
7    3      a      1   1
8    3      b      1   1
9    3      c      1   1
```

I tried to achieve this without using a loop, but I got stuck because I don't know how to make a new column *contingent on a group of rows*, not just a single one. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557675/creating-new-column-based-on-rows-being-equal-in-r) but it doesn't work if the rows are not grouped in pairs.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: With the same amount of "Option"s for each "Item" you could consider storing your data in a "matrix" like `xtabs(Answer ~ Item + Option, df)` (and with "Answer" being 0/1, you could store it as a sparse "matrix"). Then, e.g., you could use `colSums` to count "1"s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Item)%>%
  mutate(New = as.numeric(all(as.logical(Answer))))
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I run this command it creates a new column will all 0 (even for item 3, which should be a 1) and it gives me a warning: *In all(Answer) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical*. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: It takes advantage of the fact that R represents `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`, but depends on coercion to logical. Warnings don't stop it from working (warnings are not errors), but if you want to avoid them, either coerce explicitly, i.e. `as.numeric(all(as.logical(Answer)))` or test explicitly, i.e. `as.numeric(all(Answer == 1))`. Either way, `all` needs logical values to evaluate.

Comment: @alistaire: thanks! I can get rid of the warning by converting **Answer** to logical, but it is still the case that the solution doesn't work, and the new column only displays 0s.

Comment: For me, all three options produce the correct result using the data you provided.

Comment: @SolLago This works for me using the example you've given. Can you provide an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @C_Z_: it's weird.... for me it doesn't work exactly on the example that I provided. The **New** column is created, but it has all 0. However, Item 3 should have "1" in the **New** column. I don't understand what is going on because I'm sure that I am running your code on my example.

Comment: @SolLago Odd, can you try starting a new session to see if it works?

Comment: @C_Z_: that worked, which is even odder. I don't know what is happening.... you think it is some incompatibility between `dplyr` and something other package?

Comment: Ok, I marked this answer as 'accepted", but I should note that it sometimes works and it sometimes doesn't. I can't reproduce the problem consistently, but my intuition is that it has to do with some incompatibility between `plyr` and `dplyr`, and the order in which they get loaded. In the cases where this solution doesn't work, re-starting R mysteriously fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

using `data.table`

```
DT <- data.table(Item, Option, Answer)
DT[, Index := as.numeric(all(as.logical(Answer))), by= Item]
DT

    Item Option Answer Index
1:    1      a      1     0
2:    1      b      1     0
3:    1      c      0     0
4:    2      a      1     0
5:    2      b      0     0
6:    2      c      1     0
7:    3      a      1     1
8:    3      b      1     1
9:    3      c      1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using only `base R`

```
df$Index <- with(df, +(ave(!!Answer, Item, FUN = all)))
df$Index
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```